# Excel VBA continues to 'Open File' even after Cancel

Tags: excel, vba

Okay here it is. I've done a bunch of coding in the last 3 or 4 months, learned a lot, BUT, I can't figure out why this code STILL opens a file when I hit cancel at the end once the popup window comes up showing my filtered  filenames.  Any advice would be highly appreciated.

```
 Sub OpenByPartialName()

 '  Returns popup window with only filtered filenames matching
 '  Partial Filename input

 Dim WB As Workbook
 Dim Ans As String
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim path As String

 '  Folder Path Name for Forms
 path = ("S:\Forms Folder\")

     Ans = InputBox("Enter Partial filename Filter", "Open File With Partial Name Filter")

    MyFile = Dir("S:\Forms Folder\" & "*" & Ans & "*.xls")

     MyFilter = path & "*" & Ans & "*.xls"

     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
         .AllowMultiSelect = False
         .InitialFileName = MyFilter

         If .Show = 1 Then
            MyFile = .SelectedItems(1)
         End If
     End With

     On Error Resume Next
     Set WB = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)

 End Sub
```

Comment: Because you're not checking to see whether or not you *should* open the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much blood, sweat and tears later (Serious web surfing, cobbling code together and retesting) I have found an answer that works without any problems for pressing 'Cancel' at any point.

```
 Sub OpenAuditPartialName()

 '  Returns popup window with only filtered
 '  filenames matching input criteria.
 '  Filenames are saved from another code that uses 3 variables to generate a _
 '  filename 'Filename part1_Filename part2_Filename part3 Forms.xls'

 Dim WB As Workbook
 Dim Ans As String
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim path As String

 '  Folder path for Forms
 path = ("S:\Forms Folder\")
     Ans = InputBox("Enter any part of the filename to search by." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
     "Full or Partial information is OK." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Filename part1" _
     & vbCrLf & "Filename part2" & vbCrLf & "Filename part3", "Enter Partial Filename Filter")

    '  Exits on 'Cancel' as it should
    If Ans = "" Then
       Exit Sub
    End If

    MyFile = Dir(path & "*" & Ans & "*.xls")
     MyFilter = path & "*" & Ans & "*.xls"

 '*******************************************
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
         .AllowMultiSelect = False
         .InitialFileName = MyFilter

   '  Now accepts the 'Cancel' instead of continuing to open the first file
   '  in the filtered list when pressed
   If .Show = 0 Then
   ElseIf Len(Ans) Then
        MyFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
   Else
       Exit Sub
   End If
 '*******************************************
     End With
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be a dirty hack, but if you had an `Else` branch here:

```
If .Show = 1 Then
    MyFile = .SelectedItems(1)
Else
    MyFile = vbNullString
End If
```

...the code that actually opens the file could verify whether `MyFile` is empty or not before trying:

```
On Error Resume Next
If MyFile <> vbNullString Then Set WB = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
```

---

That said I think you should be handling *at least* error 53 ("file not found") here, instead of just shoving all errors under the carpet.

Also the `WB` reference isn't used. Perhaps the `Sub` should be a `Function` that returns the opened workbook, or `Nothing` if opening fails?

Comment: That was one of my attempts. But it just caused the code to not open a file either way.

Used  MyFile = ""  instead   Still failed to function.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to select a directory. If the function returns an empty string, I don't try to open the file.

```
Private Function FolderPicker() As String
'*******************************************
' returns directory path to be printed to
'   does not allow multiple selections,
'   so returning the first item in selected
'   items is sufficient.
'
' returns empty string On Error or if the
'   user cancels
'********************************************
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Const DefaultDirectory As String = "C:Path\to\default\directory\"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Choose Directory to Print to"
        .InitialFileName = DefaultDirectory
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons

        If .Show <> -1 Then
            FolderPicker = vbNullString
        Else
            FolderPicker = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

Exit Function

ErrExit:
    FolderPicker = vbNullString
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Unexpected Error: " & Err.number & vbCrLf & "Source: " & Err.Source & _
        "Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
    Resume ErrExit
End Function
```

So, you would call it like this.

```
MyFile = FolderPicker
If MyFile <> vbNullString Then
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
End If
```